# Publishing, Intellectual Copyright

Tags: publishing, intellectual-property

So effectively, I am working on creating my very own TTRPG rulebook based on my own setting and universe. The only question I got is how much of mechanics am I allowed to be inspired by?

Effectively, Warhammer 2E was a HUGE inspiration for this. I loved the percentiles, the combat mechanics, how your character begins as a no one and climbs up to being a hero. Or easily dies. I loved how the skills worked and everything.

I ask as I would really enjoy using the percentiles and combat. Not necessarily the same skills, (Read/Write is an example of one I wont be using) and more flavored to my own setting, with new skills coming in and old skills going away. I would also be changing how advance skills work entirely as well. Magic System would also be entirely changed from it, so mainly I am asking if it would be legal to use the main attribute system, secondary attribute system, and the combat system and, if so, to what degree.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. You may also want to see these related questions: [How would I go about publishing the RPGs I've created?](/questions/16414), [Can I use existing game mechanics in my own designs?](/questions/21324)